# TFS - Change to a different team on the same team project

Tags: tfs

I have 2 teams defined under the same team project and I want to switch to a different team so I could see their iteration's backlog.

Each team has its own Iterations folder and sprints.

How can I do it though TFS web access?

Thanks

Comment: I figured I could Use: http://{TFS}/CollectionName/TeamProject/TeamName. But how can I switch between the teams, through the web access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the project name on the top banner and you'll get a drop down of the most recent projects and teams.

[image: Team Selection]

If your teams aren't listed then just click "Browse All" and you can select from all the projects and teams.

[image: Browse All]